# vlc player not playing the video content

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am trying to play a .mov file in VLC player, I am able to hear the audio but not able to see the video content. In the top left corner i see the vlc icon and then VLC (Direct3D output), Any suggestions please

Comment: MOV is a container. What is the video format inside the container? Press CTRL + I and go to Advanced Info.

Comment: If you can link to the file on a server somewhere, people can look at it and give a more informed answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Within VLC, try pressing

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (View Media Info)

looking at those tabs can show you all sorts of interesting information at the file.

[image]

As was mentioned, MOV is just a container - what is embedded inside it is what is interesting. There should be at least two streams, one for the audio and one for the video. Chances are that if you can't see the video then it is probably either a poorly encoded/broken stream or that very rare file that VLC just can't play. It would be helpful to update your question with what VLC sees as the streams (and their details):

I am going to assume other video files play just fine in VLC and this is a problem specific to one file? Does that same file play just fine in Quicktime?

Answer (score 0):

.mov is usually the quicktime container... So usually you will need [quicktime](http://www.apple.com/fr/quicktime/download/), or the unofficial, but less annoying [quicktime alternative](http://www.codecguide.com/download_qt.htm)

Comment: Not an answer to the actual question.

Comment: ... and VLC supports MOV out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The very same problem occurred to me as well, I tried to update my drivers, re-install vlc and all the help I could find over the internet but none solved my problem. So, Finally I tried to De-fragment the disk where the video resided and VOILA , it worked!! all videos now work fine....

My problem was that I couldn't play all formats with vlc and the ones I couldn't play only streamed audio....

Comment: I think it highly unlikely that defragmenting the disk is what fixed your issue; defragmenting does not change the data at all.